# Server maxing out at low bandwidth?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, mac-osx

I'm running a Mac Mini Server 2.66ghz C2D, 8GB Ram OSX 10.6 Server.

I'm running a WordPress 3.1.1 install with Apache/PHP/MySQL, only serving the pages (images come from S3) per page size is 19k. When I run AB I max out @115k and 6 requests per second. It's straight across the board solid numbers. Now I know my server can handle more and I have 5megs upload so I should really be maxing out somewhere much higher.

Any ideas of where I should look first? I'm sure it must be a setting in Apache/MySQL/PHP that's limiting the server. I'm on more or less on a stock httpd/php.ini except compression is enabled, fast_cgi and mod_rewrite for WordPress.

**Update:**

```
ab -n 1000 -kc 200 127.0.0.1
```

No issues. completes the test in a few seconds. It craps out at `-n 1000 -kc 500` .. but you would expect that.

Could it be my gateway is throttling the connection and that's why it's a solid 115kpbs upload?

Comment: It could be a badly written wordpress plugin. disable any you are using to rule that out. also I assume you have already checked the apache error logs>

Comment: Did you check your Apache config?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running ab locally (over localhost/127.0.0.1)?
I would start there and eliminate network-related issues first..

After that start looking at the server's vital statistics (load average, RAM usage, Swap activity, Disk activity, etc.) when you're hitting it with your test load - that will lead you down the path of best optimization (e.g. if you're CPU-bound you may want to disable compression and see if it helps or hurts performance...).

Comment: Well I very much doubt it's a plugin as I'm running a very minimal install. my page weight is only 19k, the site with EVERYTHING totals 140k.